# Keep active menu item highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would I make it so that the item that is clicked in the menu, stays highlighted blue. So basically the active menu item.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/grundysf/j6sXg/)

I've tried using css active, but im thinking I need javascript or something.

```
 #cssmenu > ul li > a:active, #cssmenu > ul li:active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: #54cdf1;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#72d4f2, #54cdf1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#72d4f2, #54cdf1);
    background: linear-gradient(#72d4f2, #54cdf1);
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need some JS for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cssmenu li").on("click", function() {
        $("#cssmenu li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Then just style `#cssmenu li.active` the way you want it in your CSS.

Comment: +1: Particularly if the application needs to support older browsers.

Comment: What if direct URL was open?